# I keep getting an error when using an Aggregate function mySQL

Tags: mysql, average, aggregate-functions

Any thoughts on why the following doesn't work. 
The Table is called Incomes, it has 3 cols called, name, dept and salary. I want to get the name and salary of personnel in the marketing dept whose salary is less than the average salary of all employees. 
When I run the following I get ERROR 1111.

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM income
WHERE dept = "marketing"
HAVING salary < AVG(salary)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a subquery in the WHERE clause that returns the average:

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM income
WHERE dept = 'marketing'
AND salary < (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM income WHERE dept = 'marketing')
```

If by *all employees* you mean the average salary of employees of all departments, then remove `WHERE dept = 'marketing'` from the subquery.

Comment: The subquery doesn't have to be "in the WHERE clause".  We could use a join to an inline view (derived table)... which  is the pattern we would use if we were getting average salary for more than one department.

Comment: Thank you both. Still cant see why HAVING wouldn't work in lieu of AND.

Comment: @Peadar08:  `HAVING` would work, it's not about `WHERE` or `HAVING`. What's important is the *subquery*, one `SELECT` to get the average, the other `SELECT` to get detail values.  We can't reference the result of the aggregate, along with the non-aggregate detail value that makes up the aggregate, in the same SELECT.  We need two SELECTs.

Comment: @spencer7593 *doesn't have to be* yes but this is far better for performance than any join.

Comment: I would not agree about the performance difference, without a demonstration of it.

Comment: @spencer7593 any decent optimizer would execute the subquery just once to return a scalar value. This is why I mention performance.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to putting the subquery in the WHERE clause, we could use an inline view:

```
SELECT t.name
     , t.salary
  FROM ( SELECT AVG(d.salary) AS avg_salary
           FROM income d
          WHERE d.dept = 'marketing'
       ) a
  JOIN income t
    ON t.salary > a.avg_salary
   AND t.dept   = 'marketing'
```

With the inline view, we can also return the average salary, and we can calculate the difference, even a percentage difference, for multiple departments

Expanding on the query a bit, something like this:

```
SELECT a.dept
     , t.name
     , t.salary
     , a.avg_salary
     , ((t.salary - a.avg_salary) / a.avg_salary) * 100.0 AS pct_greater 
  FROM ( SELECT d.dept
              , AVG(d.salary) AS avg_salary
           FROM income d
          GROUP
             BY d.dept
       ) a
  JOIN income t
   AND t.dept   = a.dept
    ON t.salary > a.avg_salary
 ORDER
    BY a.dept
     , t.salary DESC
```